# Python regression with bounded Y values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

I have a regression problem where the target variable's values lie between 0 and 1.

Currently I have simply fit a linear regression model to the data, but this is problematic because the model is trying to fit the data linearly, when in reality it should look a lot more like a logistic regression in its output.

Aside from simply flooring and capping the predicted values from the regression model, is there a way to create a model that actually tries to fit the logistic regression curve? (There are ~10 features in this model.)

Here's an example of why this is problematic. The black line in the image below is the linear regression fit to a problem that more closely resembles a logistic regression in the sense that values should be floored and capped:

[image: there is a poor fit when attempting to fit a linear regression to a capped and floored value]

Comment: see [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)

Comment: @behzad.nouri per the wikipedia article "logistic regression is used to refer specifically to the problem in which the dependent variable is binary" - in this problem the dependent variable is not binary.

Comment: the term `logistic regression` is kind of misleading, since it is a classification not a regression model. You could have a look at generalized linear models. `statsmodels` has a framework for several link functions. A glm with a `logit` link might work.

Comment: why don't you fit by giving specific `x` conditions. i.e. different fitting equations for the different `x` ranges

Comment: If the data really are like in `Series1`, then logistic regression is unequivocally the wrong model (but it comes pretty close when using `predict_proba`). AFAIK no estimator in sklearn easily permits you to fit this type of function. This is somewhat of a structured output problem if one wanted to see it that way.